# Call language file outside "application" folder in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

How to call language file outside the application folder in codeigniter 2.

file structure is as shown below.

```
/
/application
/system
/htdocs/languages/english/common_lang.php   -- my language file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just an idea ...**

1) Create a new language common_lang.php file in `application/language` folder.

2) Include your `/htdocs/languages/english/common_lang.php` in the new  `application/language/common_lang.php`

3) Then, simply load this new language file using `$this->lang->load('common_lang.php', 'english');`

I am assuming your `/htdocs/languages/english/common_lang.php` is in the `$lang['language_key'] = "message";` format. If not you may have to figure out a way to prepare a $lang array.

Comment: Ok. Let us know how you do it. It'll be good to know another way.

Answer (score 1):

If you move file to `application/languages` folder, use `$this->lang->load()`

There is no codeigniter function loading file.

You can use `include` function like:

```
include FCPATH.'htdocs/languages/english/common_lang.php';
```

or

```
include 'htdocs/languages/english/common_lang.php';
```

`FCPATH` is root folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->lang->load('./languages/english/common_lang.php', 'english');
```

Try